# HTTP website redirect all except 1 file to https

Tags: apache, http, https, centos7, httpd.conf

I have a website where I'm wanting 1 file (version.txt) to be accessible via regular HTTP, but I want everything else to redirect to https. To do this, I added the "RedirectMatch" line below in my /etc/httpd/conf.d/somewhere.com.conf file (running centos7). Before I wanted to serve this file via HTTP, the line was a "Redirect permanent" type line. When I first made this change, I did some tests and it appeared to work; I was definitely able to access version.txt with plain HTTP, and I thought other accesses were being redirected to https. However, I just navigated to the website today and noticed it was all coming over HTTP. I have very little knowledge with websites, so I'm guessing that my testing for the redirect was faulty due to browser caching or something that tricked me into thinking it was working.

The question: in my conf.d file below, why doesn't the website redirect everything except version.txt to https? How can I change it so that it allows HTTP access of version.txt, but redirects everything else to HTTPS?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName somewhere.com
  ServerAdmin somebody@somewhere.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/somewhere.com
  ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/error_log_somewhere
  CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/access_log_somewhere combined
  RedirectMatch permanent "^(/*version.txt/.*)" https://somewhere.com$1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/somewhere.com_ssl_certificate.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/_.somewhere.com_private_key.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/_.somewhere.com_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer
  ServerName somewhere.com
  ServerAlias www.somewhere.com
  ServerAdmin somebody@somewhere.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/somewhere.com
  ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/error_log_somewheres
  CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/access_log_somewheres combined
</VirtualHost>
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

edit: bonus if you have any ideas on what fooled me into thinking it was working at first

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below redirection inside `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R,L]
```

Above rule will redirect any context to https with context.